# How to compress many nearly identical fixed-sized records?

Tags: compression

I have many 50-byte records where only 5-10 bytes differ from the last record.

The positions of the differing bytes are often the same, but any of the bytes could have changed since the last record.

Some of the changed bytes tend to be in clumps of 2-4 bytes.

Many patterns of changed bytes are re-used.

Are there specialised compression algorithms that can take advantage of the fixed-length of the records?

Answer (score 0):

Just use any standard compressor. It doesn't need to know about the record structure. It will find the matching bytes in the previous record.